# TukeyHSD p-value on boxplot after one-way anova

Tags: r, boxplot, anova, p-value, tukey

I did one-way ANOVA and Tukey test. I tried to add p-value from Tukey test to boxplot but the value on boxplot is different.
I used the following packages and codes: 
`library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

```
CR.anova <- aov( CR ~ Group, data = df)
summary(CR.anova)
tukey_hsd(CR.anova)

  term  group1   group2   estimate conf.low conf.high    p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
1 Group K02      K12    -1.90     -3.14     -0.660 0.00105  **          
2 Group K02      BASELINE   0.153    -1.06      1.37  0.987    ns          
3 Group K02      PLACEBO    0.239    -1.00      1.48  0.955    ns          
4 Group K12      BASELINE   2.05      0.838     3.27  0.000286 ***         
5 Group K12      PLACEBO    2.14      0.898     3.38  0.000215 ***         
6 Group BASELINE PLACEBO    0.0861   -1.13      1.30  0.998    ns `
```

The results on boxplot as the following:

```
ggboxplot ( Metabolite.data, x= "Group", y= "CRP",color = "black", title = "CRP" ,ylab = "Normalized value", rug = TRUE,
                        legend = "right", font.label = list(size = 40, face = "bold"), linetype = "solid", size = 1.1,
                        palette = c("#cc3300","#E7B800","#99ccff", "#003366"),fill= "Group", order = c("BASELINE", "PLACEBO", "K02","K12"),
                        bxp.errorbar= TRUE , alpha= 0.6) + border(color = "black", size= 2)+ 
  geom_jitter(aes(fill= Group),shape = 21, size = 4,color = "black", stroke= 1, position = position_jitter()) +
  theme (plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5 , face = "bold", size = 20 ),axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  theme (axis.title.x=element_blank())+ 
  theme (axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size= 16 ))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ stat_boxplot(geom ="errorbar",size= 1.1, width= 0.4)+ 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = CRP_comparisons)
```

how can I visualize the same p-value that appear in tukey test on boxplot? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2sLE.png)

Comment: Not reproducible. What is `CRP_comparisons` and where did it come from?

Comment: It looks like you've got 4 groups. So your `CRP_comparisons` object must be a list with 6 items, each one specifying the pair-wise comparisons. It should look something like: `CRP_comparisons <- list( c("K02", "K12"), c("K02", "BASELINE"), c("K02", "PLACEBO"), c("K12", "BASELINE"), c("K12", "PLACEBO"), c("BASELINE", "PLACEBO") )`